# Converge payment with ssl_recurring_flag not working

Tags: payment-gateway

I make an api request with the parameters:

url https://www.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do

```
...
ssl_show_form = true
ssl_result_format = HTML
ssl_transaction_type = CCSALE
ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator = 1
ssl_recurring_flag = 1

The following parameters are not specified for type ССSALE but they still have no effect
ssl_billing_cycle = DAILY
ssl_next_payment_date = ...
```

The payment is successful but does not fall into the Recurring section in the Control panel, only in Payments